# War God's Blessing: Can the cleric personally use it?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, domains

> At 6th level, when a creature within 30 feet of you makes an attack roll, you can use your reaction to grant that creature a +10 bonus to the roll, using your Channel Divinity. You make this choice after you see the roll, but before the DM says whether the attack hits or misses.

Can the 'creature' be the War domain using Cleric him/herself?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Yes.

From the [Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#Targets), p.80:

> ### Targeting Yourself
>
> If a spell targets a creature of your choice, you can 
>   choose yourself, unless the creature must be hostile or 
>   specifically a creature other than you. If you are in the 
>   area of effect of a spell you cast, you can target yourself.

(This applies to non-spell/ability targeting as well.)

War God's Blessing does not use phrasing along the lines of 'another creature' or 'an ally', so you are a valid target as you are a creature within 30 feet of yourself.

Additionally, you are allowed to use your reaction on your own turn so long as you have something like War God's Blessing that can trigger one then.

Comment: Can you ever not be within 30 feet of yourself?

Comment: No, you can't ever be farther than 30 feet from yourself, that was his point.

Answer (score 25):

## Yes, but why would you want to?

**[War God’s Blessing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/cleric#WarDomain)** is an extension of **[Guided Strike](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/cleric#WarDomain)**, both are options for **Channel Divinity** and pull from the same resource pool.

*Guided Strike* (gained at 2nd level) allows the war cleric to apply the +10 bonus without impacting the action economy.

> Starting at 2nd level, you can use your Channel Divinity to strike with supernatural accuracy. When you make an attack roll, you can use your Channel Divinity to gain a +10 bonus to the roll. You make this choice after you see the roll, but before the DM says whether the attack hits or misses.

*War God's Blessing* (gained at 6th level) allows the war cleric to use a Reaction to apply the same bonus to a creature. The cleric is a creature and always within 30 feet of itself, so it's a valid target.

> At 6th level, when a creature within 30 feet of you makes an attack roll, you can *use your reaction* to grant that creature a +10 bonus to the roll, using your Channel Divinity. You make this choice after you see the roll, but before the DM says whether the attack hits or misses.

A war cleric using *War God's Blessing* on itself instead of *Guided Strike* uses up a **Channel Divinity** *and* a reaction.

## Actually...

By the time the character has *War God's Blessing*, it also has two uses of **Channel Divinity**. I don't see anything that would prevent you from using both abilities to get +20 on the same attack (though there are probably better and/or more efficient uses, like making an additional attack with *War Priest* and hoping for a better roll); they have the same trigger, but are different abilities so they stack.

Comment: You could, however, do both for a net +20 to hit, if for some reason you really needed that much hit and were willing to spend twice as much to gain it.

Comment: @dsollen Good point!

Comment: +20 to spell attack + Plane Shift ftw :P  That's why you would want to.

Comment: @dsollen Abilities written in terms of "creatures within X feet of you"
 [aren't meant to include you](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/852528163837980673).

Comment: @Doval Other tweets by Crawford have indicated the exact opposite. I'm going to have to call "no confidence" on that reference.

Comment: @T.J.L.  I see the issue now. The wording he was being asked about is "[every creature within X feet of you](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/05/07/each-person-within-5-feet-of-me-gets-a-cupcake/)", not "choose (one/many) creatures within X feet of you."

Comment: "...there are probably better and/or more efficient uses, like making an additional attack with War Priest and hoping for a better roll" As far I can see a character can boost itself to get +20 on an attack, and also use the War Priest bonus to gain another attack, no? The bonus action is not a reaction, and as such the 'action economy' seems to allow it.

Comment: @Drake Sure, but *War Priest* is a more readily available resource, assuming a decent Wisdom score. *Channel Divinity* is more limited.